# display data for dates with no data

Tags: oracle11g, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am using the below query:

```
SELECT TRUNC (funddate, 'DD') "DATE",
NVL(SUM (amount),0) "TOTAL AMOUNT FUNDED PER DAY"
FROM purchases
WHERE empid= 1234 AND amount < 0
GROUP BY TRUNC (funddate, 'DD');
```

It is giving me data like:

```
4/24/2017   -1255.32
4/26/2017   -430.36
4/28/2017   -189.92
```

But I want the data to be displayed like this:

```
4/24/2017   -1255.32
4/25/2017    0
4/26/2017   -430.36
4/27/2017    0
4/28/2017   -189.92
```

I want to display the date and $0 for any day purchases were not made.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that if no such transaction date exists in `purchases`, then your query will not capture it. To resolve, you could do an outer join to a list of dates, either pulled from some other table or generated using Oracle SQL functions. You can tweak the table encapsulated by the `q2` alias if you don't want so many dates; currently it just gets the last 100 days:

```
SELECT q2."DATE", NVL(q."TOTAL AMOUNT FUNDED PER DAY", 0) AS "TOTAL AMOUNT FUNDED PER DAY"
FROM (
  SELECT TRUNC (funddate, 'DD') "DATE",
  NVL(SUM (amount),0) "TOTAL AMOUNT FUNDED PER DAY"
  FROM purchases
  WHERE empid= 1234 AND amount < 0
  GROUP BY TRUNC (funddate, 'DD')
) q
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE - ROWNUM) "DATE"
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 100
) q2 
on q2."DATE" = q."DATE"
```